# odoo IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

Any ideas on the following odoo error? I Installed the Accounting module and instead of modifying the default Sales and Purchase Taxes entries ODOO created, made my own and deleted theirs.  This error started happening when I try accessing different parts of the accounting module. I could try to reinstall the module but have had bad experiences with that.

Odoo Server Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo-9.0.20160620-2/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-9.0rc20160620-py2.7.egg/openerp/http.py", line 646, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo-9.0.20160620-2/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-9.0rc20160620-py2.7.egg/openerp/http.py", line 683, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/opt/odoo-9.0.20160620-2/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-9.0rc20160620-py2.7.egg/openerp/http.py", line 319, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo-9.0.20160620-2/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-9.0rc20160620-py2.7.egg/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo-9.0.20160620-2/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-9.0rc20160620-py2.7.egg/openerp/http.py", line 312, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo-9.0.20160620-2/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-9.0rc20160620-py2.7.egg/openerp/http.py", line 962, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo-9.0.20160620-2/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-9.0rc20160620-py2.7.egg/openerp/http.py", line 512, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo-9.0.20160620-2/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-9.0rc20160620-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 897, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo-9.0.20160620-2/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-9.0rc20160620-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 889, in _call_kw
    return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo-9.0.20160620-2/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-9.0rc20160620-py2.7.egg/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo-9.0.20160620-2/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-9.0rc20160620-py2.7.egg/openerp/api.py", line 381, in old_api
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo-9.0.20160620-2/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-9.0rc20160620-py2.7.egg/openerp/models.py", line 6054, in onchange
    record._onchange_eval(name, field_onchange[name], result)
  File "/opt/odoo-9.0.20160620-2/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-9.0rc20160620-py2.7.egg/openerp/models.py", line 5911, in _onchange_eval
    method_res = method(self)
  File "/opt/odoo-9.0.20160620-2/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-9.0rc20160620-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/account/models/res_config.py", line 169, in onchange_company_id
    self.default_sale_tax_id = isinstance(taxes_id, list) and taxes_id[0] or taxes_id
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug that was fixed on commit `1d843884e861252e395e0818b0fbf8aa074cd9d2`.

Do a git pull on your branch to update your server files,restart the server and try again.

Comment: I'm a noob with odoo so used bitnami installer to get this on our ubuntu cloud server. If I do a git pull, I'm hoping it will not screw up what bitnami did?

Comment: It should not cause any issues, we are just updating the server files.

Comment: I'm a noob, so it looked easier to stop using bitnami them figure out how to make git replace that was installed. Lots of config differences it seems between bitnami odoo install and the standard source.  So I ended up installing a true version of odoo community. now working through how to migrate data to this new odoo install.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in "res_config.py" you have a list you work with the first element is probably empty
To avoid this problem, you can use taxes_id[0] inside if taxes_id: